# For in loop inside a function

Tags: javascript

Hi so I am getting trouble with this piece of javascript code. I want to make a function  that lets me know if there is an item that is not in the basket or not.

```
const amazonBasket = {
  glasses: 1,
  books: 2,
  floss: 100,
};

function checkBasket(basket, lookingFor) {
  for (item in basket) {
    if (item === lookingFor) {
      return `${lookingFor} is in your basket`;
    }
  }
  return `That is not in your basket`;

}

checkBasket(amazonBasket, camera);
```

Comment: If for some reason you want to leave most of the code untouched (e.g. you can't refactor as Black Mamba's answer suggested), the fix is simple with your current code. Add a `let found = false` above the loop. Inside the loop, in the `if` condition you would set `found = true;` then `break;`. Then `return found ? 'found message' : 'not found message';` at the end of the function.

Comment: @MattU `loops` exit the function when anything returned from them that's why they're preferred over the `.map`, `.forEach` iterators

Comment: I know. Apparently I had `break` on my mind the whole time... :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call the function like this `checkBasket(amazonBasket, "camera");` instead where amazonBasket is an object and camera is the key you want to look up.

A better/cleaner solution would be

```
function checkBasket(basket, lookingFor) {
  return basket[lookingFor] ? `${lookingFor} is in your basket` : `That is not in your basket`;
}

// Invoking the right way
const amazonBasket = { glasses: 1,books: 2, floss: 100};
checkBasket(amazonBasket, "camera");
```